# datagridview não preenche os campos (Windows Form) - C# - Visual Studio Comunnity 2015

Tags: c#

Olá, estou com um problema, entro com o seguinte problema: Quando entro com os dados no datagridview ele não "puxa" do banco de dados as informações pra colocar na tela. O BD é MySQL, Localhost e naum tem erros. Segue o código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace SistemaVendas
{
    public partial class Caixa : Form
    {
        public Caixa()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        int precototal = 0;
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; database=sistemacsharp; username=root; password=");


        private void txtnumprod_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.KeyChar==13)
            {
                txtquantidade.Enabled = true;
                txtquantidade.Focus();
            }
        }

        private void txtquantidade_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)

        {
            txtnumprod.Clear();
            txtquantidade.Clear();
            try
            {
                string txt = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE ID='" + txtnumprod + "'";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(txt, con);
                con.Open();
                MySqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (r.Read())
                {
                    int preco = int.Parse(txtquantidade.Text.ToString()) * int.Parse(r[6].ToString());
                    precototal = preco;
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(dataGridView1.RowCount, r[0], r[1], txtquantidade.Text.Trim(), r[6], preco);
                }
                lbltotalitens.Text = "" + (dataGridView1.RowCount - 1) + "";
                lbltotal.Text = "" + precototal + "";
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ee.Message,"Este É Um Erro Vindo Do Banco de Dados");
            }
            txtnumprod.Focus();
            txtnumprod.Clear();
            txtquantidade.Enabled = false;
            txtquantidade.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: quando pressionar uma tecla no campo quantidade, a primeira coisa que faz é limpar o campo?!

Answer (score 0):

Seu código possui vários problemas, primeiro deles é o que o Rovann citou, o clear do campo quantidade antes de ser utilizado.

Segundo se você tiver algum problema no seu código a conexão não será fechada e não está dando dispose nos objetos.

Note que eu to utilizando o "using" e eliminei os "Clear" antes do uso deles (porque não fazia nenhum sentido).

Tente dessa forma:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace SistemaVendas
{
    public partial class Caixa : Form
    {
        public Caixa()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        int precototal = 0;
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; database=sistemacsharp; username=root; password=");


        private void txtnumprod_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.KeyChar==13)
            {
                txtquantidade.Enabled = true;
                txtquantidade.Focus();
            }
        }

        private void txtquantidade_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string txt = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE ID = @NumProd";

                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(txt, con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumProd", txtnumprod.Text);
                    con.Open();
                    using (MySqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (r.Read())
                        {
                            int preco = int.Parse(txtquantidade.Text.ToString()) * int.Parse(r[6].ToString());
                            precototal = preco;
                            dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(dataGridView1.RowCount, r[0], r[1], txtquantidade.Text.Trim(), r[6], preco);
                        }
                        lbltotalitens.Text = "" + (dataGridView1.RowCount - 1) + "";
                        lbltotal.Text = "" + precototal + "";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ee.Message,"Este É Um Erro Vindo Do Banco de Dados");
            }
            txtnumprod.Focus();
            txtnumprod.Clear();
            txtquantidade.Enabled = false;
            txtquantidade.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Agora deu erro: input string was not in correct format

Comment: Colocou um breakpoint pra ver onde acontece o erro ? Provavelmente é nesses inputs de quantidade, preço total, onde você tá dando Cast pra Int. verifique esses detalhes.